# Apache can't connect to http://localhost/. Port is changed to 81

Tags: windows, apache

I've just installed apache2.2 and installed it, but to get it running I had to change it listening port to 81. But the thing is now that I cant connect to it through localhost. The only thing I get is a login window and when I type in the authentication information that I think is my windows login. I get:

error '8002801c'

Error accessing the OLE registry.

/iisHelp/common/500-100.asp, line 17

The computer is a winxp and I've opened the ports out and no firewall is blocking apache.

Comment: Sounds like the user Apache is running as doesn't have access to the Registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the machine has another webserver running, probably IIS. 
You can uninstall that through the configuration screen.

Try http://localhost:81/ to get the apache install.